# Why is currency format incorrect?

Tags: asp.net, windows, localization

In my code, I have...

```
litCost.Text = string.Format("{0:c}", orderEntity.Cost);
```

And the output is...

> $2.00

Also, it wants dates submitted in US format.

And yet....

In the website's IIS setting for .net Globalization Culture and UI Culture is `English (United Kingdom) (en-GB)`.

And in Windows Region settings in Control Panel, the location is set to United Kingdom and the currency symbol is `£`.

This switch of format happend, I think, after a reboot.

Any ideas?

Comment: Please try to print Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture and Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I set...

```
<globalization uiCulture="en-GB" culture="en-GB" />
```

in web.config.

I have no idea why the previous setting stopped working.